# Nicer proof that Yoneda embedding is continuous?

Tags: category-theory

So if $\mathcal{C}$ is locally small, we have the Yoneda embedding $Y:\mathcal{C} \rightarrow [\mathcal{C}^{op},Sets ]$. This preserves all limits in $\mathcal{C}$, and a comment here: [An application of Yoneda Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107849/an-application-of-yoneda-lemma) says that showing this is just a matter of reformulating the definition of a limit. How is this?

I thought about how I would show that $Y$ preserves limits, and all I could think of was this: Suppose $L$ is the limit in $\mathcal{C}$ of some diagram $D$. Take some cone over $YD$ in $[\mathcal{C}^{op},Sets]$ with base $P$ and write $P$ as a colimit of representable presheaves. (I think) you can then use the Yoneda embedding to show that $L$ is a cocone over the elements of $P$, and the unique map $P \rightarrow YL$ from the universal property of $P$ will also work to show that $YL$ is indeed the limit.

Is this proof correct, and what is the easy proof that I've missed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $\{L \to D_i\}$ is a limit diagram in $C$, then for every $X \in C$ we have that $\{\hom(X,L) \to \hom(X,D_i)\}_i$ is a limit diagram in $\mathsf{Set}$, which means precisely that $\{\hom(-,L) \to \hom(-,D_i)\}_i$ is a limit diagram in $[C^{op},\mathsf{Set}]$.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that I didn't see that means I need to go understand the Yoneda lemma better, I suppose...

Comment: You only need the definition of $Y$, not anything else.

Comment: For a categorical novice, it might be worthwhile to explicitly state that the last step requires not just that $\{\hom(X,L) \to \hom(X,D_i)\}_i$ is a limit diagram, but that for each $X$, but also that the morphisms in these diagrams are natural in $X$.

Comment: Yes this is the existence of $Y$.

Comment: As an improvement of this question: can we argue that the contravariant Yoneda functor $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow Set^{\mathcal{C}}$ sending C to [C,-] also preserves limits? That is my feeling looking at Martin's proof.

Comment: There is no such functor $C \to Set^C$. Do you mean $C^{op} \to Set^C$? This is continuous by simply apply what has been proven to $C^{op}$ (since $Set^{(C^{op})^{op}}=Set^C$).

Comment: It wasn't you who wrote that functor in this post: mathoverflow.net/questions/9917/yoneda-embedding-vs-dual-vector-space? I meant the contravariant version of $\mathcal{C}{\longrightarrow}Set^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$.

Answer (score 1):

I give a rephrasing of Martin Brandenburg's answer, since I noted some confusion (see also: [Why is Yoneda embedding continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389441/why-is-the-yoneda-embedding-continuous?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Given a diagram $D:I\to \mathcal C$, we want to show that the object $Y(\lim_i Di)$ in the functor category $[\mathcal C^{\operatorname{op}},\operatorname{Set}]$ is the limit of the diagram $Y\circ D:I\to[\mathcal C^{\operatorname{op}},\operatorname{Set}]$ (with projection maps $Y(p_i):Y(\lim_i Di)\to Y(Di)$ coming from the projection maps $p_i:\lim_i Di\to Di$). Recalling that "limits in functor categories are computed pointwise" (Theorem 6.2.5 in Leinster's Basic Category Theory), it is equivalent to show that $Y(\lim_i Di)(C)=\hom(C,\lim_i Di)$ is the limit of the diagram
$$
\operatorname{ev}_C\circ Y\circ D:I\to \mathcal C\to [\mathcal C^{\operatorname{op}},\operatorname{Set}]\to \operatorname{Set},i\mapsto D_i\mapsto Y(Di)(C)=\hom(C,Di).
$$
for each $C\in \mathcal C$. Then just note that $\operatorname{ev}_C\circ Y=\hom(C,-)$, and since we know that representables are continuous, i.e., $\operatorname{ev}_C\circ Y(\lim_i Di)=\hom(C,\lim_i Di)$, we are done by the above.

Comment: +1. The fact about limits being pointwise computable is important and should have been included in the original answer

Answer (score 0):

(Copied with minor stylistic modifications from my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4247728/580423))

---

In fact, we don’t need to use that (co)representables are continuous to show that Yoneda is continuous; we can instead prove directly that Yoneda is continuous and derive that (co)representables are continuous as follows:

Given a category $\textbf{C}$ and a diagram $\text{F}\ \colon\ \textbf{D}\to\textbf{C}$ with limit $\text{lim}\left(\text{F}\right)$, denote the Yoneda embedding of $\textbf{C}$ $$よ_{\textbf{C}}\ \colon\ \textbf{C}\to\text{Psh}\left(\textbf{C}\right)$$ and the “cones over $F$ with given vertex” functor $$\text{Cones}_{\text{F}}\ \colon\ \textbf{C}^{\text{op}}\to\textbf{Set}$$ and observe the following chain of isomorphisms natural in $\text{c}\in\textbf{C}^{\text{op}}$: \begin{align*}よ_{\textbf{C}}\left(\text{lim}\left(\text{F}\right)\right)\left(\text{c}\right)\ &\simeq\ \text{Hom}_{\textbf{C}}\left(\text{c},\ \text{lim}\left(\text{F}\right)\right)\\ &\simeq\ \text{Cones}_{\text{F}}\left(\text{c}\right)\\ &\simeq\ \text{Cones}_{よ_{\textbf{C}}\circ\text{F}}\left(よ_{\textbf{C}}\left(\text{c}\right)\right)\\ &\simeq\ \text{Hom}_{\text{Psh}\left(\textbf{C}\right)}\left(よ_{\textbf{C}}\left(\text{c}\right),\ \text{lim}\left(よ_{\textbf{C}}\circ\text{F}\right)\right)\\ &\simeq\ \text{lim}\left(よ_{\textbf{C}}\circ\text{F}\right)\left(\text{c}\right)\end{align*} where

- The first isomorphism is tautological from the definition of $よ_{\textbf{C}}$.
- The second isomorphism is tautological from the definition of the limits of a diagram as representing the functor of cones over said diagram with vertex the argument.
- The third isomorphism is from that the Yoneda embedding is fully faithful.
- The fourth isomorphism is tautological from the definition of the limits of a diagram as representing the functor of cones over said diagram with vertex the argument. (We implicitly use the fact that $\text{lim}\left(よ_{\textbf{C}}\circ\text{F}\right)$ exists, which follows from that $\textbf{Set}$ is complete and that limits in functor categories that exist pointwise compute pointwise.)
- The fifth isomorphism is by the Yoneda lemma.

So that $よ_{\textbf{C}}\left(\text{lim}\left(\text{F}\right)\right)\simeq \text{lim}\left(よ_{\textbf{C}}\circ\text{F}\right)$ $\blacksquare$

*P.s.:* We can now use the pointwise evaluation of limits in functor categories that exist pointwise in the codomain (and the completeness of $\textbf{Set}$) to deduce that (co)representables are continuous.

Comment: Why does this prove that $よ$ sends the universal cone of $F$ to the universal cone of $よ\circ F$? As far as I can tell, this argument only shows that $よ$ sends the vertex of the cone of $F$ to the vertex of the cone of $よ\circ F$. Did you implicitly use some result or am I overseeing something?

Comment: @ShaVuklia Fair question. The vertex isomorphisms in the post extend in a straightforward way to isomorphisms that relate (Yoneda of the universal cone of $\text{F}$) to (the universal cone of the limit of Yoneda of $\text{F}$) in a manner that commutes with the canonical projections. Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to draw out the diagram.