# Products in Set and Fiber Products in an arbitrary category

Tags: category-theory

I’m told that, given a category $C_z$ of objects over $z\in C$, if $h:T\to z$ is a fixed object in this category, letting $F$ be the functor such that $$F(X)=Mor_z(T,X),$$ then $F$ transforms fiber products over $Z$ to products in the category of sets.
However, I’m having trouble understanding this fact—A fiber product in $C_z$ is a product of $f,g$ as objects in $C_z$.This functor takes $f\times g$ to all arrows $k$ such that $f\cdot p_1\cdot k=h=g\cdot p_2\cdot k$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the respective projections given by the fiber product. How is this related to the product in the category of Sets?

Answer (score 3):

By the definition of the pullback, such an arrow $k$ is the same as a pair of arrows $(a: T \to Y, b: T \to X)$ such that $f \circ a = g \circ b = h.$ In other words, this is the same as an element of the product $F(X) \times F(Y)$.

This is an instance of the more general [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424188/nicer-proof-that-yoneda-embedding-is-continuous) that the Yoneda embedding preserves limits: here you basically have $yX(T) \times yY(T) \simeq y(X \times_z Y) (T).$